# Why is bash ignoring the ending double quote (")

Tags: bash, line-endings

I have this file:

```
http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/I_Cuestionario_general_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/IV_Ingresos_y_recursos_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/VI_ambito_escolar_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/VII_ambito_laboral_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/VIII_ambito_comunitario_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/IX_Atencion_Obstetrica_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/X_ambito_familiar_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
```

And this bash script:

```
while read p; do
        echo  "\"$p\""
done < file.txt
```

I would expect the same file but with double quotes around each line, but this is what bash is outputting:

```
"http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/I_Cuestionario_general_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
"http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/IV_Ingresos_y_recursos_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
"http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/VI_ambito_escolar_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
"http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/VII_ambito_laboral_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
"http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/VIII_ambito_comunitario_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
"http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/IX_Atencion_Obstetrica_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
"http://www.beta.inegi.org.mx/contenidos/proyectos/enchogares/especiales/endireh/2016/tabulados/X_ambito_familiar_estimaciones_endireh2016.xlsx
```

Anyone know why bash is behaving this way? And how to output both `"` double quotes? (beginning and end)

Comment: it works fine on my machine. what is your environment, like bash version?

Comment: `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release`. I'm starting to think it's a problem with the input file and the newline chars :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm near certain that the line endings on your input file are CR/LF rather than just LF. This would output:

- `"`;
- the web address;
- a CR returning the cursor to the beginning of the line;
- `"`; and, finally,
- moving to a new line.

Capture the output to a file and pass it through a dump utility like `od -xcb`, that should show you the raw bytes being output.

As a test, creating a file consisting of the two lines `123<CR>` and `456`, I see:

```
pax> while read p; do echo "\"$p\""; done <testfile
"123
"456"
```

which seems to indicate the problem is as described.

Comment: Thanks, I did run it through xxd and apparently `0d` hex was the problem (which is indeed carriage return). I was confused because Sublime Text wasn't able to detect it when I regex searched for `\r`, but I assume it's a bug :/ I fixed it now :) thank you!

Comment: @jake2389 Sublime Text is probably just treating it as a DOS/Windows-format text file, with CR/LF line terminators (which I'm sure is what it is), rather than treating the CR as part of the line (which pure unix programs will generally do).

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble escaping the leading and trailing double quotes, you can just use single quotes around your `echo` statement. Any double quotes inside of single quotes have no significance in terms of defining a string literal, and vice versa:

```
while read p; do
        echo '"$p"'
done < file.txt
```

Comment: That just prints literally `"$p"` for each line.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I think that's what he was trying to show. But it's badly communicated.